# Facebook Open Graph Debugger errors

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having a lot of problems sharing my site URLS. When sharing a new post, the image associated to the post is not shown.

I tried the Facebook Open Graph Debugger, but it doesn't work as supposed.

1st try to check the url I get this error:

[image: Error parsing input URL]

2nd try I get this other errors:

```
og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image 'http://img1.woman.es/82/ad/85/michelle-calvo-presentacion-coleccion-roberto-verino-640x689.jpg' will be used instead. Consult http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler for more troubleshooting tips.
```

[image: og:image was not defined]

As you can see the og:image is present, but facebook can't see it.

Could you please help me with this? I'm getting mad trying to find the problem.

Page with OG's: http://www.woman.es/moda/tendencias/famosas-rinden-tendencia-botas-altas.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my damn English.

Comment: Image seems to show fine by now.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve the problem (add a width and a height to the og:image):

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="640" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="917" />
```